# Vue 3 Composition Api , Vue-router 4 Naigation guards throw an Error when using it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia, vue-router4

When I try to use navigation guard from Vue-router 4, my code is no longer working it show a errors with undefined (push) from Pinia store `router.push('/')`. Here is my code:

```javascript
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import manageStaffRoutes from "./manage.staff.js";
import authRoutes from "./login.js";

import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/auth.store.js";

const routes = [...manageStaffRoutes, ...authRoutes];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
    const auth = await useAuthStore();
    const publicPages = ["/login", "/super-admin-login"];
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
    if (authRequired && !auth.user) {
        return "/";
    }
});
export default router;
```

then in my  store I have this code , where I am trying to redirect the user after successfully login

```javascript
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("userAuth", () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const userData = ref(null);
    const errorMessages = ref(null);

    const user = computed(() => {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    });

    if (user.value) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `${user.value.token}`;
    }

    async function login(email, password) {
        try {
            const data = await axios.post("api/v1/users/login", {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            });
            if (data.status === 200) {
                userData.value = data.data;
                localStorage.setItem(
                    "user",
                    JSON.stringify(userData.value.data)
                );
                await router.push("/"); // the error
               
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return (errorMessages.value = error.response.data.errorsToSend);
        }
    }

    const logout = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await axios.post("api/v1/users/logout");
            console.log(data);
            if (data.status === 201) {
                user.value = null;
                localStorage.removeItem("user");
                await router.push({ name: "login" }); // the error
            
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // return (errorMessages.value = error.response.data.message);
        }
    };
    return { login, user, errorMessages, logout };
});
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the **single responsability principle** I suggest you to change the `login()` function on the store, **remove the router push** to let the store only authenticate your user. By doing this the redirection is handled by the calling funcion an not by the login.

**AuthStore**

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("userAuth", () => {

    // .... 

    async function login(email, password) {
        try {
            const data = await axios.post("api/v1/users/login", {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            });

            if (data.status === 200) {
                userData.value = data.data;
                localStorage.setItem(
                    "user",
                    JSON.stringify(userData.value.data)
                );
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return (errorMessages.value = error.response.data.errorsToSend);
        }
    }
};
```

**Router**

```js
import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/auth.store.js";

// ...

router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const publicPages = ["/login", "/super-admin-login"];
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);

    if (authRequired && !auth.user) {
        return "/";
    }
});
```